# Treeview like view for vertical grouping in Kendo UI Scheduler

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm new to kendo UI. I'm trying to implement a scheduler with Kendo UI Scheduler. For simple scheduler I'm able to configure it properly. but I want a vertical resource grouping like tree view (Parent-Child Relation)

I followed their tutorial http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/resources-grouping-vertical
But it is not working like what I want.

[image]

```
[                   
    {                   
        "RoomTypeId":6,                 
        "RoomTypeName":"Single Bed Room",                   
        "Rooms":[                   
            {                   
                "RoomId":21,                    
                "RoomNo":"1006"                 
            },                  
            {                   
                "RoomId":22,                    
                "RoomNo":"1007"                 
            },                  
            {                   
                "RoomId":23,                    
                "RoomNo":"1008"                 
            }               
        ]                   
    },                  
    {                   
        "RoomTypeId":5,                 
        "RoomTypeName":"Double Bed Room",                   
        "Rooms":[                   
            {                   
                "RoomId":26,                    
                "RoomNo":"1001"                 
            },                  
            {                   
                "RoomId":27,                    
                "RoomNo":"1002"                 
            },                  
            {                   
                "RoomId":28,                    
                "RoomNo":"1003"                 
            }                   
        ]                   
    }                   
]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code in full in jsbin or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

The Scheduler built-in views don't currently offer the option to show different nested groups for each parent group.

There is one possible workaround which might help: you can create a custom view that extends from any of the default ones and is tailored to your particular needs. You can find a project that shows how to do this [in the Telerik forums](http://www.telerik.com/forums/showing-different-people-in-different-groups-using-kendo-timeline-view). You'll find the logic in toDoView.js inside the Scripts folder.